# Github for Windows - Adding tags

Tags: tags, github-for-windows

Is there a way to manage repositories tags in Windows client of Github?

(and if not, how could I do this ?)

Comment: Are you using the command-line client for git?

Comment: No, I use the GUI. But I can use command-line if needed.

Comment: Looking at VonC's answer, looks like you can't yet do it with the GUI. You'll have to use the command-line version (it's better in the long run anyway ;) ).

Comment: It is possible now (2020). See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13862778/6309) below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would still need to open a bash from the "GitHub for Windows" GUI and use the CLI.

```
git push --tags
git fetch --tags
git tag -a ...
```

(See [`git tag` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))

There was a similar question for [GitHub for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/308585/how-can-i-create-a-tag-with-github-for-mac), and in both cases, the tags namespace (`refs/tags`) isn't yet taken into account by the GUI.

---

Since May 2020, 7+ years later:

"[Create and push tags in the latest GitHub Desktop 2.5 release](https://github.blog/2020-05-12-create-and-push-tags-in-the-latest-github-desktop-2-5-release/)"

> With today’s 2.5 release, you can create and view your tags directly from GitHub Desktop. Now when you push to GitHub.com, any tags created in Desktop are automatically included. GitHub Desktop also notifies you when you’ve created tags but haven’t yet pushed them, so you don’t forget to share your latest tag with the rest of the team.

[image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/10404068/81434697-70277500-911b-11ea-9b30-d5da8a80a664.gif?ssl=1]

Comment: Should be `git fetch --tags`, although `git pull --tags` may still work (with some complaints).

Comment: @robbrit true, I have removed the `git pull --tags` to avoid confusion